# Xamarin Forms Maps remove pin does not update map

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm trying to create a xamarin forms maps project and I'm having trouble removing individual pins. I've seen other questions regarding this but did not see viable answers. The Pins.Clear method works but for some reason Pins.Remove does not. Any help would be appreciated thank you

**EDIT**

Someone has asked for my code and it's nothing fancy.

```
Pin oMiddle = null;
    private void map_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var m = (Map)sender;
        if (m.VisibleRegion != null)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Lat: " + m.VisibleRegion.Center.Latitude.ToString() + " Lon:" + m.VisibleRegion.Center.Longitude.ToString());
            if (oMiddle == null)
            {
                oMiddle = new Pin { Position = m.VisibleRegion.Center, Label = "Middle", Address = "test address" };
            }
            else
            {
                mRemovePin(oMiddle);
                oMiddle.Position = m.VisibleRegion.Center;
            }
            _map.Pins.Add(oMiddle);
           // mGetUsersInRadius(10000);
        }
    }   
    private void mRemovePin(Pin oPin)
    {
        _map.Pins.Remove(oPin);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  How are we possibly supposed to help you if you don't bother to show us what you're doing?

Comment: I've edited my question to include the code. As I described, it's nothing fancy. It's a simple remove pin from map.

Comment: That can't possibly be your real code.  The exact scenario you're using to remove the pin matters - is it in an event handler?  Is it in a background thread? - and that's why I asked you to post the *relevant* code, not some made up sample

Comment: I've updated the post to give you what you wanted. And as you can see. It's in an event handler. I've also tried invoking remove pin from the UI thread hence the reason it's separated to a function.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue as well. I tried the same thing with native project, the issue doesn't exist. I've created an issue in the Github.  You can follow it up by this link: [https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2411](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2411).

Comment: Thanks for helping, I've also found that I can move the pin but it seems that the reference is never cleared for the map control